# How to Auto-update the repeating table by selecting the checklist of information in Infopath2010?

Tags: sharepoint-2010, infopath

using infopath 2010, sharepoint 2010

To do - I have 3 view forms and in first form i have checklist of information when i tick/select it should appear in third form which is repeating table.

Step1
what i did is create a set field rule if checklist A is true then repeating table equal 'A' it only work for one selection from checklist if more than one select the answer is still one selection in repeating table.

Step2
created the data connection of datalist in sharepoint connected with infopath repeating table but doesn't work

so how to autoupdate the repeating table by selecting the checklist of information, kindly guide me.
thanks..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this it takes a little bit of coding - I don't believe there is any way directly in the interface (rules/conditions/etc). You found out the drawback pretty quickly - the rules only populate the first item. It isn't a huge pain but isn't exactly easy.

What you want to do is use the "changed" event for the checkbox list and have your code manually update the form XML (add nodes under the repeating section). They will automatically show up on your form as you manually change the XML.

It is a bit of work but comes out quite nicely. Only try to implement it if you really need the functionality and know a bit about infopath and coding. We used the technique to create a "summary" list of many separate checkbox lists.

Comment: Thanks Ktharsis, Yes i understand need to use coding as i have tried all the different methods of rule/action to populate the repeating table by select the option from checklist.. simply doesn't work So is it possible to guide me in coding (C#) with an example, it would be great.. thanks in advance!!